# int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method' - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

The traceback says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dex.py", line 37, in <module>
    n=int(raw_input)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

and the code:

```
t[n]=1
```

where t is `t=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0]`
and n is `int(raw_input)`

What I'm basically trying to do is to set the index `n` of `t` to `int(raw_input)`.

Comment: `raw_input` is a function. You forgot to call it.

Comment: `raw_input` is a function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`raw_input` is a *function*, you need to *call* it and pass the *result* of that call to `int()`:

```
n = int(raw_input())
```